# 403 Forbidden On First Page Load

Tags: php, security, internet-explorer, caching, http-headers

I am trying to send users to a pre-populated page on a website, but it seems the website needs a prior visit before allowing it. On the first page load a 403 Forbidden error is given, however on subsequent loads it works fine.

I assume this is a security feature of some type, is there a way to circumvent it and send users to this page without error?

To repoduce:

- Use Internet Explorer or Firefox
- Go here: https://www.united.com/ual/en/us/flight-search/book-a-flight/results/?f=ORD&t=LAX&d=2018-03-28&r=2018-03-31&sc=7,7&px=1&taxng=1&idx=1
- For some reason Chrome is unaffected.

On your first load you will get an alert:

```
The page encountered an error processing your request.
```

Console says:

```
DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
inprivate.htm
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
results
DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
inprivate.htm
HTML1514: Extra "<body>" tag found. Only one "<body>" tag should exist per document.
results (67,1)
HTML1424: Invalid character
results (2366,108)
HTML1424: Invalid character
results (2366,191)
HTML1521: Unexpected "</body>" or end of file. All open elements should be closed before the end of the document.
results (4099,522)
ajax error: 403 Forbidden; Requested URL: /ual/en/us/flight-search/book-a-flight/flightshopping/getflightresults/rev
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2eff, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002eff.
results.
```

I've tried the following solutions, none have worked:

- Load an iFrame on the page prior to sending them to this page to get cookies, the site does not allow iFrames.
- Send a POST request to the site in the same way the flight search on the homepage sends it. This also did not work and gives the same error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you asked the developers of that site? You should also check their terms of service to see if you are allowed to do this in the first place.

Comment: I have not, I will try but I think a response is unlikely. I see nothing in their terms and conditions that would disallow linking directly to flight information.

Comment: I think your app can fall under this: _"User agrees not to use any device, software or routine to interfere with or attempt to interfere with the proper working of this website or any activities conducted on this site."_ since you're interfering with the intended flow of the site (people going through their search page etc). Sites like this usually have a pretty strict TOS.

Answer (score 0):

tried in firefox(59.0.1 64bit), chrome(65.0.3325.181) and ie(11).

just in ie there is an error, "The page encountered an error processing your request" - but with clicking ok everything seems for me to work well.
ok 2 of 4 times there is an error in ie.

Comment: I am hoping to make it work in all browsers, including IE on the first page load.